# Check datetime field before insert

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I want to be able to check the *datetime* field on the latest record on my table before another record is inserted. I use this to populate the *datetime* field, when a record is inserted:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

As for now I have a validation for other fields but I want to add a validation on the *datetime* field aswell. It should check for the latest record on my table and check the difference on the *datetime* field and $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); and if the difference is 5 seconds or less, it should now allow insert of a new record to the table. An error message will be displayed like this:

```
    }else if(trim($checktime) == '') {
    $error = 'Please wait 5 seconds before insert'; 
   } if($error == '') { //Run the code
```

How would $checktime look like for my example above?

Comment: personaly I'd better move this logic into the database, create trigger (on before insert) for example

Comment: or, without triggers, check this `TIMEDIFF(now(),ts) > '00:00:05'` before inserting

Comment: @k102 actually I would keep that logic **out** of the database. A database should have nothing to do with flood control. Also having the DB handle it means you still need a connection to it, and keeping the number of connections down is usually one reason for such a limitation. It should be handled with session or SHM instead. That's a lot faster anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly query the database for the latest datetime. Something like these should do the trick:
SQL:

```
SELECT MAX(`mydate`) AS mydate FROM `tablename`;
or
SELECT `mydate` FROM `tablename` ORDER BY `mydate` DESC LIMIT 1;
or if you have a primary key auto-increment column called id this may be fastest:
SELECT `mydate` FROM `tablename` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;

<?php
$last_insert_time = strtotime(); # Use the result from the database query as the parameter
$now = time();

# If the difference between the last inserted entry and the current time is less
# than five seconds perform an error action.
if (($now - $last_insert_time) < 5) {
    $error = 'Please wait 5 seconds before insert';
}
```

Comment: Awesome, glad you found it useful. Thank you for accepting the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

1) First take last record date value by using this query

```
SELECT dateVal FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1;
```

2) Find the Difference of two dates by using this

```
$timeFirst  = strtotime($dateVal);
$timeSecond = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$checktime= $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
```